# Django: atomic DateTimeField read and write

Tags: django, datetime, atomic

I have a Django model `User` with field `balance`, and maintain a `balance_last_updated` `DateTimeField` with it.

In order to update balances race-condition free, I need to atomically read and then set `balance_last_updated` in my Django view. That way, any threads updating the balance will do so for distinct time periods (correct?).

How do I do this? Note that I am using MySQL MyISAM tables, which [seem to not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214406/199754) Django [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions).

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support transactions *at all*, not Django's transaction handling specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Django 1.4, you can use [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) to achieve this. But **only** if your database backend supports transactions. MyISAM doesn't, so I suggest switching to the InnoDB engine or PostgreSQL if atomicity (or ACID in general) is of any importance for your project.